# Guess the disney song from the initials number 1

Tags: music

I will give you the initials of the lyrics to a disney song and you need to try and guess which song it is.

W Y W U A S
M N D W Y A
A Y H D
W C T Y
I Y H I I Y D
N R I T E
W Y W U A S
A D D
F I K
S B T T W L
T S F O
T S L
L A B O O T B
S I C T Y
W Y W U A S
Y D C T
W A S I B
T P A G O T
O O T I T
T H T P T M A W C T
W Y W U A S
W Y W U A S
M N D W Y A
A Y H D
W C T Y
I Y H I I Y D
N R I T E
W Y W U A S
A D D
F I K
S B T T W L
T S F O
T S L
L A B O O T B
S I C T Y
W Y W U A S
Y D C T


**HINT:**

> This song was released in 1940

Comment: William Pennanti, you got my upvote! Everybody was so fast haha, you got 3 answers within the 15 minute lockout period! In future, I don't think you'd need to include the entire song lyrics - I can't speak for rhsquared or SteveV, but I certainly only needed the first line/six letters before I knew what the correct answer was.

Comment: Done that on my second one

Comment: That one is a lot tougher (and a lot less obvious!) Great improvement :D

Comment: @WilliamPennanti I think the correct answer should go to El-Guest because he was faster than me by 5 secs.

Comment: Please upvote if you liked this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the answer to this

> When You Wish Upon A Star?

Comment: well done. I cant accept yet or rate up but plz rate the question

Answer (score 1):

The first one is:

> "When You Wish Upon a Star"

Comment: Close one!! Great answer! Think I got you by 5 seconds this time ;) +1 from me!!

Answer (score 1):

i think it is:

> When you wish upon a star

Comment: Close one!! Great answer! Think I got you by 31 seconds this time ;) +1 from me!!